# My dropdown option have value but not showing on form for selection

Tags: angularjs

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="tehsil">Select Tehsil</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select class="selectpicker" id="tehsil" multiple data-actions-box="true" name="tehsil" data-live-search="true"
            ng-model="tehsil">
            <option ng-repeat="tp_id in tehsil" value="{{tp_id}}">{{tp_id}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

when i inspect element they look like this i am getting this data on page load using ng-init:

```
[<option ng-repeat="tp_id in district" value="ATTOCK" class="ng-binding ng-scope">ATTOCK</option>][1]
```

Comment: may in question i am not much clear but anyone can ask for his answer clarity..thanks

Comment: what is the problem you are facing here? Can you be more clear?

Comment: @nircraft values are not showing on page .where i can select any value but value present when i inspect the page.

Comment: please anyone help me out to this problem

Comment: @Cristiano Soares can you help please

Comment: share a demo code on plunkr please :)

Comment: @Shashank Vivek check out on this link https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/5kHXdL with plugins.in this plugin i also want search and select all option with divider line.

Comment: I am using bootstrap 3 and jquery2.2

Comment: @WasimAkram the shared demo link has no code. :D Please check once

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: @Shashank Vivek  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cxe5XBuPhYABDwhTub0O_mZ8hajTXoWs kindly find demo code

Comment: ooops!! remove .txt from file extension

Comment: @ Shashank Vivek waiting your response

Answer (score 0):

I have created this Plunker based on the code you provided in the google drive, this appears to be doing what you are asking already? When you select the values get assigned to the ng-model 'sl_tehsils'. Please see plunker as I have printed the resulting values to the screen https://plnkr.co/edit/AIsFEXAGQLUCCsC4ajqw?p=preview.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="tehsil">Select Tehsil</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select class="selectpicker" id="tehsil" multiple data-actions-box="true" name="tehsil"
                        data-live-search="true" ng-model="sl_tehsils">
                    <option ng-repeat="tp_id in tehsils" value="{{tp_id}}">{{tp_id}}</option>

                </select>
            </div>
            {{sl_tehsils}}
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.tehsils =["Ahmadpur East Tehsil", "Alipur Tehsil", "Arif Wala Tehsil", "Astore Sub-division"]; 
});
```

Comment: actually i want to make it multi select dropdown with search bar .For that purpose i am using jquery libraries .when i include the libraries that time no value present in dropdown....i think you got my point...thnks a lot for your concern

Comment: Make sure you are injecting JQuery in before you load in angular files as this can cause issues within Angular. In summary, you are trying to make a multi-select dropdown where you can filter the results? E.g. if you started typing 'Ahma" you would want the dropdown to only contain 'Ahmadpur Eat Tehsil'?

Comment: @ Craig Oldfield  am sure jQuery is loaded first before angular js.yes you are right i want this thing as you say.....one more thing dropdown data load on form using ng-init .

Comment: There are many ways to go about achieving a searchable multi-select dropdown, none that I have used have been native to AngularJS. I just did some quick research and came up with UI-Select which is native to Angular and appears to do what you are after, link: https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/ (click on the multiple selection plunker in the bottom list). Otherwise i typically use bootstraps since it is clean and effective, https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/forms/multiselect/ (again scroll down for the multi-select with search). Hopefully these help you!

Comment: dear @Craig Oldfield thanks a lot...in mdbSelect there is any issue of bootstrap version ..because currently i am using bootstrap3.

Comment: Is there any particular reason preventing you from upgrading to a more recent version with the features you desire? What are the errors you are seeing? I looked around there are some implementations for bootstrap 3 however they are heavily reliant on jquery or bootstrap-multiselect plugins, see: [link](https://www.webslesson.info/2017/05/bootstrap-multi-select-dropdown-with-checkboxes-using-jquery-in-php.html).

Comment: Hi,

I've 3 selects on my form and I'm loading the items using angularjs from a database.

Sometimes  the items aren't loaded into the Boostrap-Select. If I remove the selectpicker class from the selects everthink works fine all the time. The biggest problem is that I don't receive any error

Comment: I really can't debug without a plunker of your example there is too many moving parts and it could be something specific with your environment. If you can mockup the issue into an environment that I can edit (plunker etc.) i'd be happy to sit down and try to work it out with you.

Comment: Im glad to hear it! If my comment helped it'd be great to mark it as the answer... If you solved it a different way it would be great if you add your own answer and mark it as correct to help future people who might stumble upon a similar issue!

Comment: I upgrade my bootstrap version because first one was complied in cache and was unable to upload the new content..@Craig Oldfield comments also help me many more...

Comment: can we change url in same ajax and with same form data  after success response from first call???

Comment: I am not really sure what you are asking, what I would advise though is to close this question off (as described above by either accepting my answer or adding and accepting your own)... then post another question with all the updated code. Just to keep things clean with this question :)

Answer (score 0):

I upgrade my bootstrap version because first one was complied in cache and was unable to upload the new content.

Currently i using bootstrap 3.3.4